# nginx - rtmp multi-stream just fails to stream to a source randomly

Tags: linux, nginx, rtmp

Mind you I talk about stream services here like Youtube, but rtmp streaming is used widely.

OS: Debian Testing
nginx: 1.22.0-3.1

My issue is that I have a full rtmp config set up for multi-streaming. It works. But randomly it fails to push to this or that site.

For example, a few days ago Trovo failed.
I changed the rtmp url to their secondary URL.
Yesterday? Youtube stopped working.

Thing is, I enabled this live dashboard where I can see my stream stats and it's all great. According to nginx. But it still won't show up on Youtube for example. It's saying I should start my stream. Like it's kinda stuck.

- Why do they randomly fail?
- How could I make nginx keep trying to reconnect?
- Can I somehow split this up, so I could restart individual streams?

I checked the logs but there is nothing in them about this.